# How can I find out which data won't cast?

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2000

I have a SQL table with a date field defined as char(8), or 20090609, and a time field defined as char(4), or 1230. I am moving this data into another table and I want to combine the two fields and put them in a smalldatetime field in the new table. My query is like this:

```
INSERT NewTable(eventdate) 
SELECT
  CAST((datecol + ' ' + substring(timecol, 1, 2) + ':' + substring(timecol, 3, 2)) as smalldatetime)
FROM OldTable
```

When I run this, I get an error:

> The conversion of char data type to
>   smalldatetime data type resulted in an
>   out-of-range smalldatetime value.

I've tried checking len(datecol) and len(timecol) to make sure that they are at least the correct number of characters. I have no idea how I can find the offending data, any suggestions? The database is SQL2000 and I'm using SMO 2008.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is probably out of the range of acceptable smalldatetime values
January 1, 1900, through June 6, 2079

**EDIT** On closer inspection I think the substring parameters for the second portion of the time may be incorrect (which may be the whole problem) updated below to reflect  substring(timecol, 3, 2)

**New Approach** this sql does assume that all dates are 8 characters in length, and all times are 4.

```
Select SubString(DateCol, 1, 4) as tehYear, 
Substring(DateCol, 5,2) as tehMonth, 
SubString(DateCol, 7,2) as tehDay,
SubString(TimeCol, 1,2) as tehHour,
Substring(TimeCOl, 3,4) as tehMinute,
*
from OldTable
where
(SubString(DateCol, 1,4) > 9999 or SubString(DateCol, 1,4) < 1753)
OR (Substring(DateCol, 5,2) > 12 or Substring(DateCol, 5,2) < 1)
OR (SubString(DateCol, 7,2) > 31 or SubString(DateCol, 7,2) < 1)
OR (SubString(TimeCol, 1,2) > 23 or(SubString(TimeCol, 1,2) < 0)
OR (Substring(TimeCOl, 3,4) > 59 or Substring(TimeCOl, 3,4) <0)
```

Try casting to datetime and seeing if there are any dates that fall outside of that range to identify your problem data.

```
    SELECT
    CAST((datecol + ' ' + substring(timecol, 1, 2) + ':' + substring(timecol, 3, 2))
    as datetime)
    FROM OldTable 
    Where CAST((datecol + ' ' + substring(timecol, 1, 2) 
    + ':' + substring(timecol, 3, 2)) as datetime) 
    > Cast('06/06/2079' as datetime) or CAST((datecol + ' ' 
    + substring(timecol, 1, 2) + ':' + substring(timecol, 3, 2)) as datetime)
    < Cast('01/01/1900' as datetime)
```

Comment: Good approach, this + checking the month between 1 and 12 and the day between 1 and 28 should filter out a lot of the errors

Comment: I also like the approach, but with it I get "The conversion of a char data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range datetime value."

Comment: You know what, I think your substring is off for the second portion of your timecol, should be substring(timecol, 3, 2))

Comment: @cmsjr Oops! my example had a typo (and then everyone followed my lead), but the code I'm actually using is correct. I reran this example with the correct substring positions and I still receive the same error.

Comment: Darn. Well, time to look more deeply at the component parts. The new sql above should take us down another level, it assumes 8 character date columns, 4 character time columns, and has no handling for improper number of days within a month for months with less than 31 days.

Comment: The second approach worked great! There were a couple of rows with a date of 19000000.

Comment: This approach is inferior to using ISDATE.

Comment: Well, ISDate had already been tried and did not resolve the problem. But I guess I can accept inferior but functional over superior and un-useful.

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
SELECT datecol, timecol
FROM OldTable
WHERE ISDATE(datecol + ' ' + substring(timecol, 1, 2) + ':' + substring(timecol, 2, 2)) = 0
```

That will show you which rows cannot be converted successfully.

Comment: That query is returning rows with data like date:20081024 and time: 1657. When I try to cast the data by itself, it casts fine.

Comment: @OrbMan, the substring to get the second half of the timecol was incorrect in my example (and yours). I changed it to substring(timecol, 3, 2) and used your example, however, it results in the same error.

Comment: @scotty2012, are you reading his example correctly? His query will show you the ones that will NOT work. So if you want to do this in one shot without reporting, look for the ones where ISDATE = 1.

Answer (score -1):

If you run the query in query analyzer it should tell you what row the error occured!

Comment: Nope, I just get 0 row(s) affected.